# fancybox can't open on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

if i add the fancy box code in my main page of html then fancybox not open on page load... if i add the fancybox code in footer of page then fancybox open but my site slider cant't show ... and i want if some one site open then on page load fancybox show and slide show also show

here is my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>123</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Forum_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tms-0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tms_presets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/atooltip.jquery.js"></script> 

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .slider_bg {behavior:url(js/PIE.htc)}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <div style='clear:both;text-align:center;position:relative'>
        <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body id="page1">
<div class="body6">
    <div class="body1">
        <div class="body5">
            <div class="main">
              <p>
                <!-- header -->
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <div class="ic">sara rubab</div>
<!-- / header -->
<!-- content -->
                <article id="content">
                    <div class="slider_bg">
                        <div class="slider">
                            <ul class="items">
                                <li>
                                    <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="banner">
                                        <strong>Frnd<span>Best</span></strong>
                                        <b>congra</b>
                                        <p>
                                            <span>Lorem ipsum dolamet consectetur<br>
                                            adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor aliqua enim ad minim veniam, quis nosinci- didunt ut labore et dolore.</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="banner">
                                        <strong>what<span>one</span></strong>
                                        <b>life of tipsum</b>
                                        <p>
                                            <span>Lorem ipsum dolamet consectetur <br>
                                            adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor aliqua enim ad minim veniam, quis nosinci- didunt ut labore et dolore.</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="banner">
                                        <strong>NWE<span>EX</span></strong>
                                        <b>sdsd</b>
                                        <p>
                                            <span>Lorem ipsum dolamet consectetur <br>
                                            adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor aliqua enim ad minim veniam, quis nosinci- didunt ut labore et dolore.</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </article>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here is fancybox code on page load with youtube video

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yambi.tk/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.yambi.tk/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#yt").click(function() {
                $.fancybox({
                        'padding'        : 0,
                        'autoScale'      : false,
                        'transitionIn'   : 'none',
                        'transitionOut'  : 'none',
                        'title'          : this.title,
                        'width'          : 680,
                        'height'         : 495,
                        'href'           : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                        'type'           : 'swf',
                        'swf'            : {
                            'wmode'              : 'transparent',
                            'allowfullscreen'    : 'true'
                        }
                    });
                return false;
            });
        });
        $('#foo').bind('click', function() {
              alert($(this).text());
            });
            $('#foo').trigger('click');
    </script>
</head>

<body onload='$("#yt").trigger("click");'>

        <p><a id="yt" title="" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y8G7wMgIPY&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=1"></a></p>
```

Comment: Try to put *$("#yt").trigger("click");* at the end of your *$(document).ready(function(){...});*

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code starting from the html and open youtube videos in `embed` mode :

```
<p><a id="yt" title="" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3l8MwU0IjMI?wmode=opaque&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=1"></a></p>
```

then your fancybox code could be as simple as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#yt").fancybox({
        'padding': 0,
        'width': 680,
        'height': 495,
        'type': 'iframe' // using embed mode
    }).trigger("click");
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8da5u/)**